# python cgi script prints object as a string when raw string is sent using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I am using javascript to send the data `{"hello":"world"};` to a python cgi script as follows (This script works)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>I am a header</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var httprequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
httprequest.open("POST","hello.cgi");
var content={"hello":"world"};
httprequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
httprequest.send(JSON.stringify(content));
httprequest.onload=function(){
if(httprequest.status==200){
alert("");
document.write(httprequest.responseText)};
}//end of onload
</script>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
</doctype>
```

this is my python cgi script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
    import sys,os
    import cgi
    sys.stderr=sys.stdout
    import traceback
    print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    print "<h1>YES</h1>"
    formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print((formData))
except Exception as e:
    #print(e.message)
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

**This cgi script takes takes the javascript object convert it to a string, erases all contents in the html document and writes to the browser the following**

```
  YES
FieldStorage(None, None, '{"hello":"world"}')
```

**Question 1**

I do **not** want this cgi script to write `'{"hello":"world"}'` as a **string** in fieldstorage I want it to write the string as a dictionary `{"hello":"world"}` /object

**Or is there a way in javascript to encode the javascript string to a GET or post format and send the output as if it is submitting a html `<form>` with the data to a python cgi script? will this solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that cgi.fieldstorage is primarily for receiving data from HTML form tags. Hence it is not the right tool for json strings

Here is how I solve this issue after some late night mental wrecking. I use json module in python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
try:
    import sys,os,json
    import cgi
    sys.stderr=sys.stdout
    import traceback
    print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
    print "<h1>YES</h1>"
    data=json.load(sys.stdin) #convert json string to python object (answer)
    print "<script>var t="+str(json.dumps(data))+"</script>" # I can also take the string and put it in a html script
    #print((formData))
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Afterwards I attempted calling my javascript object `t` in the browser and it worked as expected..what a relief...